# HDMI display output working only in Ubuntu and not in WIndows

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I apologize in advance if this is not the right place to post this question but any kind of help or direction would be very helpful as I've tried all my possible solutions.

My machine is a Dell XPS 9570. I was running Windows and Ubuntu in dual-boot and everything was great. At a certain point, the HDMI output stopped working on the windows side, I'm still able to detect the dedicated GPU and the monitor from the HDMI cable but there is no output. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS7so.png)

On Ubuntu, everything works fine, both from a USB drive and also from the partition.

I believed that the problem was in Windows and I performed a clean install of windows/intel and Nvidia drivers. Nothing worked.

On the Nvidia control panel I don't have access to the Display settings tab: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8BbT.png)

I tried disabling the intel driver to see if Windows picks up the Nvidia card but it defaults to Windows basic display driver.

I even tried on a different SSD, with a fresh install of Windows, and still nothing.

I remember that a while ago I disabled the GPU in Ubuntu because I was not using it and I was trying to gain a bit of battery savings... I don't remember the steps I took, Is there a way to restore everything to default?

Again Any kind of help or guidance would be greatly appreciated as I don't know what to do.

Thanks a lot for your help and expertise!

Comment: Did you get the latest from [NVIDIA Driver Downloads](https://www.nvidia.fr/Download/index.aspx?lang%3Dfr)?

Comment: Hello @harrymc, thanks for your answer. Yes, I have the latest installed =/

Comment: Try the [Dell drivers](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ae/product-support/product/xps-15-9570-laptop/drivers).

Comment: Still no luck, even tried rolling back the BIOS but nothing. I've seen a lot of people having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the GPU in Ubuntu should not affect Windows.

To test if something went wrong with Windows *and* Ubuntu,
try a Live Ubuntu media.

If the Live boot also cannot use the HDMI, you might have a hardware error
with the port or the video card. You could try another video card to test.

Comment: From a Live boot, it works without issues. I've posted on Dell's community forum but I don't think that I will get any help there. There are a lot of people with the same issue and no useful solution. I guess my only solution is to buy a thunderbolt hub =/

Comment: Does the HDMI problem coincide with any Windows update? Check *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update > View update history*. Try also an Nvidia driver dating from before the problem arrived.

Comment: Hard to tell but I will try, at this point it doesn't hurt ahahah Thanks again for helping out